# Get the Shared Preferences "Key" according to the "Value" in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

What I am trying to do is to delete the row from the listview in android. I am successful in doing this. But now my problem is when I delete the row values from ListView at the same time I want to delete the Value and the key from my Shared Preferences.

> How I want to do that is: When I delete the row Value from the list. I wanna get the value of that row and check in my Shared Preferences for that value. If that "Value" is there then I will get the "Key" based on that "Value". I know there is a way like: `sharedPrefEditor.remove(key);` but what I am thinking that if there is something related to: sharedPrefEditor.remove("key","Value"), then it would have been great because this way I can easily delete the "specific"key/value pair. I hope you guys are g

HINT: I have saved the "Keys" for the Shared Preferences according to the TimeStamp i.e The time when I was saving the "Key".

Please be free to fire any questions to me anytime.
Thanks you.

EDIT: HERE IS THE CODE WHEN I AM ADDING THE VALUES TO THE ARRAYLIST.

```
 // get the list values from SharedPreferences
        Map<String, ?> allEntries = MapActivity_sp.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().toString().contains("passedAddressValue")) {
                if (getpassedAddressValue.contains(entry.getValue().toString())) {
                    //nothing
                } else
                    getpassedAddressValue.add(entry.getValue().toString());

            }
        }
        adapter = new InflateLocations(this, getpassedAddressValue, lv);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is when you are populating the list view in your adapter, that you add the key as a tag to each view. Then when you want to delete a row, you can retrieve the tag for that list item, which will be the key you need to delete.

EDIT: Based on your sample code, I'd suggest modifying your `InflateLocations` adapter to retrieve the key given a position:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, ?> allEntries = MapActivity_sp.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().toString().contains("passedAddressValue")) {
        if (!getpassedAddressValue.contains(entry.getValue().toString())) {
            getpassedAddressValue.add(entry.getValue().toString());
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
adapter = new InflateLocations(this, getpassedAddressValue, keys, lv);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then in `InflateLocations`, store the `keys` in a field (say, `mKeys`) and add a method:

```
public class InflateLocations extends ... {
    private List<String> mKeys; // initialize in constructor
    ...

    public String getKey(int position) {
        return mKeys.get(position);
    }
}
```

And when you process a list item click, you can retrieve the key by querying the adapter:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    InflateLocations adapter = (InflateLocations) parent.getAdpater();
    String key = adapter.getKey(position).toString();
    // process key
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for a quick reply. If you can provide me a more accurate answer with an example then I would appreciate it.

Comment: @KaranvirVerma - Am I correct in assuming that you are populating your list view from values stored in your shared preferences? It would be easier to show an example if you provided a little more detail about how your code works.

Comment: @KaranvirVerma - Given that code, it might be easier to just maintain a separate array of keys. As you build the `getpassedAddressValue` list, create a separate list of the keys corresponding to each element you add. Then you can easily retrieve the key by position of the selected item you are removing.

Comment: I am not able to get what you are trying to say. I will just keep it simple. Is there a way that I can get the keys from shared preferences editor based on the values of that particular key? Because ultimately i will be saving all the data in shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Should i use the getKey() method inside the getView()? And i am not using the click on the actual listview object. I am performing  the click for deletion on the View Object in the inflater file.Check out the second Answer that is posted by me.

Comment: And one more thing the retuen statement at the end of the getkey () method is not returning String. It is asking to return a string.

Comment: @KaranvirVerma - I added a call to `.toString()` for the retrieved key. I don't at all get what your code is supposed to be doing. Where is this code located? What's `rowView`? What's `stringAdd`? What's `position`? Whatever the case, you can use my basic idea, but store the `keys` list somewhere other than the adapter; somewhere that your code can access and you can retrieve the key by position and delete the shared preference value. I'm sorry my suggestions don't match your code structure, but that's because you have provided no information about your code structure.

Comment: Sorry about that. rowView is the View object that binds all the views of a row of the list and stringAdd is an arraylist object that is initialized with the getPassedAddressValues inside the Inflator class constructor.

Comment: @KaranvirVerma - Okay, so I still don't get why you can't use my solution. What's the problem?

Comment: @Todd: check it out sir. I have posted the full code for what I am doing. Hope it helps.

Comment: I got that working sir. Thanks a lot for baring with me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
{  rowView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            stringAdd.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });}
```

Answer (score 0):

@TedHopp: Here is my full code for the inflator class. Check it out please. I have included the getKey() method also. But i dont think so its making sense as it is out of the getView() method.

```
    package c.silent.it.keep.keepitsilent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InflateLocations extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> stringAdd;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;
    String[] stringMd;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editSP;
    Context context;
    ListView listview;
    private List<String> mKeys;
    // int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    //  public InflateLocations(List_Locations mainActivity, ArrayList<String> stringAddress, String[] stringMode, ListView lv) {
    public InflateLocations(List_Locations mainActivity, ArrayList<String> stringAddress, List<String> keys, ListView lv) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        stringAdd = stringAddress;
        context = mainActivity;
        mKeys=keys;
        listview = lv;
        //stringMd = stringMode;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return stringAdd.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView modeTv;
        TextView addresssTextview;
        // CheckBox switchForService;

        // ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_list_locations, null);
        holder.modeTv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.modeTextView);
        // holder.switchForService = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.switchForService);
        holder.addresssTextview = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.addresssTextview);
        holder.addresssTextview.setText(stringAdd.get(position));


        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                editSP = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editSP.putInt("listItemPosition", position);
                editSP.putString("SelectedAddress", stringAdd.get(position));
                editSP.apply();
                Intent startactivity = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ServiceButton.class);
                context.startActivity(startactivity);
            }
        });

        rowView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                stringAdd.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return rowView;

    }
    public String getKey(int position) {
        return mKeys.get(position);
    }


}
```